# How to fix non-default gnome-terminal opening failure?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, chroot

I've recently updated one of my ubuntu(gnome) chroots to 18.04 from 16.04 LTS (before official release to 16.04 LTS). The `chroot` has the gnome target not gnome-desktop and has come with `xterm` (instead of gnome terminal) because of this. I have attempted to install gnome-terminal using a simple

```
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

and this works fine until I attempt to launch it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> no longer functions, and the gnome terminal will not open, whether attempted via xterm or launcher. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> regains function after gnome terminal removal.